# Bash command for output of only directories based on regex

Tags: regex, bash

I am not too savvy with shell commands. But I was wondering if there was a way to list all ONLY the directories (no files) that contain a certain regex parttern?

For instance:

```
a/
   /dir1
      /d_332
         file1.txt
   /dir2
      /d_123
         file2.txt
   /dir3
      /dir4
         /dir5
            /d_444
               file3.txt
```

The regex I want to use is `d_\d+` to find all directories that start with `d_` and have a series of numbers. This it Python regex. I am not sure how different it is compared to bash regex

This command would give me an output of:

```
a/dir1/d_332/
a/dir2/d_123/
a/dir3/dir4/dir5/d_444/
```

Comment: try :  find . -type d

Answer (score 2):

Use the `find` utility:

```
find path -type d -regex '.*/d_[0-9]+'
```

`path` would in your case be `a`; it's the top of the directory tree `find` is going to search.

This uses two filters:

1. `-type d` filters for directories, and
2. `-regex '.*/d_[0-9]+'` filters for paths (full paths) that match the regex `.*/d_[0-9]+`. The regex is applied to the full path as `find` prints it, not just a part of it; that's why the `.*` at the beginning is required.

Those entries in the directory tree that match both filters are printed.

There's also a `-regextype` option that allows you to use a few different flavors of regular expressions, so you may want to take a look at the manpage.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
 find . -type d -name 'd*[0-9]*'
```

Comment: Make a directory `d_1foo` and run the command again; `d_1foo` will show up in the results despite not matching the regex. `-name` takes a glob, not a regex.

Comment: @ruakh , my expression matches number anywhere in dir name . may be i should change that to what you are saying. didn't release he wants numbers at the end.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to express quite the same pattern that OP wants as a glob. Which is a pity; `-name` would otherwise be quite nice here because it applies its pattern to the basename of the path instead of the full thing. On the other hand, I suppose having to prepend `.*/` to all regexes is not an insurmountable problem.

Comment: @Wintermute . instead of name , you can use -wholename and  match the entire string. man find shows the following for pattern :  -name pattern
             True if the last component of the pathname being examined matches pattern.  Special shell pattern matching characters (``['', ``]'', ``*'', and ``?'') may be used as part of pattern.  These characters may be matched explicitly by
             escaping them with a backslash (``\'').

Comment: True, but that would be combining the worst of both worlds. The nice thing to have for this would be something that applies a regex (like `-regex`) to the base name of the path (like `-name`). `-wholename` (or, more portably, `-path`) applies a glob (that OP can't use) to the full path (which is mildly inconvenient).